# how to convert azure app insights api response to C# models

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

so i am able to call app insight's api "https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/xx/xx/xx" from my C# code.

i can get the json response.

[image]

i have this response in json and i want to serialize it into C# objects. do i have to create matching C# classes my self or is there any built in c# models i can use and serialize them?

Answer (score 0):

Not really a direct answer to your question, but instead of consuming REST API directly and doing the conversion/serialization yourself you can simply use [`Application Insights .Net SDK`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ApplicationInsights.Query/).

The SDK will do all the necessary conversions for you and give you nice C# objects. The source code for this is also open source and is available here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/applicationinsights/Microsoft.Azure.ApplicationInsights.Query.

You can take a look here for all the models available to you for direct use here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/applicationinsights/Microsoft.Azure.ApplicationInsights.Query/src/Generated/Models.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if you choose to use app insights api, that means you didn't add any other sdk into your project, that means there's no any built in models for you.

And if you choose to use sdk instead, [here's a sample for it](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Tools/CSharp-Sdk), and per my testing, it only provides `QueryResults` as the response, here's my testing result， and this is the [introduction](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization/AAD-Application-Setup) for preparation. Pls note, you need wait for a while to make the newly added role to take effect. If you can't find the api permission mentioned in the document, you can search for it like what I did.

[image]

[image]